# Cant use a class from an implicitly linked .dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dllexport

I am having trouble using the class `Shape` from my Shape.dll in my ShapeTester.cpp (another .dll project.)

```
//Shape.h

#ifdef SHAPE_EXPORTS
#define SHAPE_API __declspec(dllexport)

class SHAPE_API Shape
{
public:
Shape();
Shape(int sides, int sideLength, int apothem);
~Shape();

int Perimeter();
double Area();
private:
int sides;
int sideLength;
int apothem;
};
#endif

------------------------------------------------------------
//Shape.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Shape.h"

Shape::Shape() : sides(0), sideLength(0), apothem(0)
{
}

Shape::Shape(int sides, int sideLength, int apothem) : sides(sides), sideLength(sideLength), apothem(apothem)
{
}

Shape::~Shape()
{
}

double Shape::Area()
{
    //implementation
}

int Shape::Perimeter()
{
    //implementation
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
//ShapeTester.cpp (this is in another DLL project)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ShapesTester.h"
#include "Shape.h"

bool ShapesTester::Test()
{
    Shape myShape = Shape(3, 9, 5); // error here; cant resolve symbol Shape

    return myShape.Area() == 67.5;
}
```

I included SHAPE_EXPORT in my preprocessor directives, i can get .dll, .lib

Properties > configuration Properties > Linker > Input > set Additional Dependencies to Shape.lib

Properties > configuration Properties > Linker > General> Additional Library Directories (pointed to location of Shape.Lib)

Properties > configuration Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories (pointed to location of Shape.h )

Comment: Please post the compiler/linker errors you get - verbatim. Without seeing the errors, how do you expect us to do anything but guess?

Comment: i sorta did verbatim it says Cannot resolve symbol 'Shape'

Comment: that *not* posting an error message *verbatim*. That's just posting your *interpreted* version of the error message. Just post the raw version already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Shape` class should be outside the `#ifdef` block, not inside it.  THe code as it is will not declare the `Shape` class unless the `SHAPE_EXPORT` symbol is defined.

What you want to do is

```
#ifdef SHAPE_EXPORTS
#define SHAPE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SHAPE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class SHAPE_API Shape
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I going to try this now but i defined `SHAPE_EXPORT` in my preprocessor directives

Comment: hey wow that worked, or well at least im getting new errors. For the line 'Shape myShape = Shape(3, 9, 5);' its now saying type SHAPE_API is incomplete and theres no overloads that takes 3 args but there is...

Comment: that did it thank you so much ive been trying to solve this since last night.

can you explain what was going on exactly? i thought defining the `SHAPE_EXPORT` preprocessor directive was enough

Comment: Usually the false branch of the #ifdef block is: "#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)", that way code that implicitly links to the DLL automatically imports.